# Is there any way to solve for $x$ in this equation: $xy + y = y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to see if there is any way to solve for $x$? I'm told Option 1 is correct and I think I understand it but why is Option 2 incorrect?

Option 1: subtract both sides by $y$
$$xy + y -y = y - y\\
xy = 0$$
No solution as either $x$ or $y$ could be zero

Option 2: factor out $y$
$$y \cdot (x + 1) = y\\
\frac{1}{y} \cdot y \cdot (x + 1) = y \cdot \frac{1}{y}\\
(x + 1) -1 = 1 -1\\
x = 0$$
Granted we still don't know what y is, but can't we be sure that $x = 0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with mathematical typesetting. Most users here don't like to read things like y xy+y-y=y-y xy =0

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the highest voted answer says it all.

Comment: If the OP gave detail on the question and there is a good answer, it does not follow from the EoQS that the question must be closed

Answer (score 3):

Your equation $$xy+y-y=0$$ simplifies to
$$xy=0$$ so $$x=0$$ or $$y=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $x=1$ and $y=0$.

I think the right reasoning is the following.

We need to solve $xy=0$.

If $y=0$ so we see that all real number is a root of the equation.

For $y\neq0$ we obtain $x=0$.